# Can I use Adobe Acrobat X Pro to rotate an image 90 degrees only if its width is less than its height?

Tags: imagemagick, adobe, acrobat

I am using a script with a subroutine that uses ImageMagik to do this now.

It uses the command `-rotate "+90<"`  (ref. http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#rotate)

Is it possible to do this with Acrobat? Support for ImageMagik is ending.

Comment: What do you mean that support for ImageMagick is ending. That is not true from ImageMagick end. What software is dropping support for ImageMagick.

Comment: The company will not allow open source programmes

Comment: OK. I now understand.